# Oracle null and unique constraint

Tags: database, oracle, constraints

Does a unique constraint include a not null constraint?

I have a case that one attribute `cellPhone` can be `NULL` but cannot be repeated, so I give it 2 constraints: "not null" and "unique", in a case of updating the record, if user didn't enter a value I put 0 in the field, so it makes this exception:

```
 SEVERE: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST1.OSQS_PARENTS_CELLPHONE_UK) violated
```

What should I do in the `UPDATE` case?

**EDIT**
here's the definition of table ddl

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST1"."OSQS_PARENTS" 
(   "PARENT_NO" NUMBER(38,0), 
"PARENT_NAME" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
"PARENT_ID" NUMBER(38,0), 
"PARENT_EMAIL" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
"PARENT_CELLPHONE" NUMBER(38,0)
)
```

and here's an image of the constraints
[image]

and here is the update statement

```
    Parent aParent;      //is an object I pass through a function
String SQlUpdate = "UPDATE OSQS_PARENTS P SET P.PARENT_ID=?,P.PARENT_EMAIL=?,P.PARENT_CELLPHONE=?"
            + " where P.PARENT_NO=?";
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(SQlUpdate);
        pstmt.setLong(1, aParent.getId());
        pstmt.setString(2, aParent.getEmail());
        pstmt.setLong(3, aParent.getCellPhoneNo());
        pstmt.setLong(4, parentNo);

        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }
```

Comment: Is that a legitimate constraint failure though (ie. might you already have a record with 0 in the constrained column)?

Comment: Please show the full CREATE TABLE and constraint definition as well as the corresponding UPDATE statement.

Comment: @Simon, in the first update that the user didn't enter a value of cell phone, I update the field to be zero, in the second user who didn't enter cell phone number, I try to update the record with zero value too, so here's the problem, I don't know what is the value I should put in the update statement.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name, it might complicate the question, since the table has many attributes.

Comment: As @a_horse_with_no_name says - we'd be in a better position to help if you post your table definition including the constraints, and the statement you're using. However, it sounds like you're not using `NOT NULL` correctly - if that value can be an "unknown" (that you're replacing with zero), should it really be `NOT NULL` and unique?

Comment: @Simon, I am using Oracl SQL developer to create the table and constraints , in the SQL section it show only the creation of table without constraint, did u have any idea from where I can find the constraint definition?

Comment: @Alaa there should be a tab labelled "Constraints" after "Columns" and "Data". Failing that you can run a `SELECT` on `all_constraints`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name,@Simon, please check the Edited section.

Comment: @Alaa: No need to post a screenshot. If you click on the SQL tab in that window, you should see all the needed SQL. But the bigger problem is, that the screenshot does not match your error message. The error refers to a constraint `OSQS_PARENTS_UK4CELL_PHONE` but that is not visible from what you have posted

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I have just changed the name of the constraint of cellphone, in sql part there's no constraints !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it sounds like this:

cellPhone  must be unique.  When user does not input value, you mark it as a 0.  Thus it fails when you try to insert multiple 0 values into a 'UNIQUE' column.

I believe you need to drop the NOT NULL constraint on the column (allow it to be UNIQUE yes, but allow NULLS).

Then when user inputs no value, use it as a NO value (unknown = null <> 0 -- 0 is a known value )

throw an IF into your statement, if value then what you have, otherwise SET IT TO NULL!\

```
pstmt.setNull(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

Comment: +1. The `OSQS_PARENTS_NULLCHECK` constraint does make sense, assuming that each record needs either `PARENT_EMAIL` or `PARENT_CELLPHONE`, and setting unknown values to NULL (allowing them in both columns covered by the constraint) is the best method

Comment: The why behind this is that Oracle implements a UNIQUE constraint with an index, and NULL values are unindexed.  That's why you can have multiple nulls that don't "collide."

Comment: @Adam: NULLs are unindexed, except in the case of multi-column indexes where at least one of the columns is not null.